# Can I set Grub to not boot a default OS?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I'd like the computer to wait at the Grub screen for me to make a choice, rather than picking one option and running with it. Is there a way to have *no* default operating system in Grub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `GRUB_TIMEOUT` to a very big value or to `-1` (infinite). This is by default set at 10 seconds. To change it, edit `/etc/default/grub` file using the following command in terminal:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub
```

After you finished to edit that file, save it and don't forget to update your Grub using the following command:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>t</kbd>
- Type command, `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT` value to -1. It will make GRUB wait indefinitely until you manually select an entry and hit enter,
  It should look like

  `GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1`
- save it. Close gedit. Now run

  `sudo update-grub`